# Matching Android WebView text size to TextView text size

Tags: android, webview, textview

Is there an easy way (possibly non-programmatic?) to match the size of text in a WebView to that in a TextView?

I have a (XML-specified) TextView  which has no text size or appearance attributes:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblExerciseSummary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblWeekTitle"
    android:textColor="@color/home_screen_text_colour"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp" />
```

And also a WebView which has no text size or appearance attributes:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblRunDescription"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblTest"
    android:background="#00000000" />
```

When I put text into the TextView (using setText()) and HTML into the WebView (with loadData() and the text itself in a `<p>` element with no extra CSS/inline styling set), the two Views display the text in different sizes (the WebView seems to default to a larger size than the TextView.)

What's the best way of ensuring that my WebView text always matches the TextView text in size, and possibly in other appearance -- is it maybe just luck that it's even the same font face?

I'm guessing the TextView is picking up some defaults from the theme/style/device settings, but I'm also guessing that the WebView has some kind of default stylesheet which may *not* be picking up the same settings?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope. I gave up and used TextViews for everything I was doing.

Comment: ok, thx. Not an option for me. I'll write an answer when I (hopefully) find a solution

Comment: I did idly wonder if you can programatically apply a stylesheet to the WebView with the (dynamcially-read) pixel size of the TextView. But as I could get away without it (I wrote some slightly hacky code to add the highlighting/other text effects I needed to TextView) I didn't explore that avenue in any detail.

Comment: One last question, were you able to use the same font in a WebView and a TextView? I'm using Georgia in the webview right now

Comment: Ah, I didn't look into that, because my WebView used the same font as my TextView by coincidence anyway. That would have been on my "make sure once I've got the rest of this working..." list, I'm afraid. Good luck!

Comment: You are right, they look pretty much the same. I won't look into it unless my client complains :) Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Matt, you could try using the method `setTextZoom()` in your `WebView`:

```
thisWB.getSettings().setTextZoom(thisTV.getTextSize());
```

`thisWB`: your `WebView`

`thisTV`: your `TexView`, from where your are going to get the text size for the `WebView`

**Note that the method `setTextZoom(int textZoom)` is API Level 14 (Use it if your are developing an app for Android 4.0+).**

Link: [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setTextZoom%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Given that setTextZoom takes a percentage, whereas getTextSize returns a size in pixels, I can't quite see how this would work, though? (Also, I'm also developing for API level 8+. In the end, it didn't matter, as I just changed my approach to avoid mixing WebView and TextView anyway...)